Trackpad glitching out on Ubuntu 24.04
I dual boot my machine (HP Folio 9480m), Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 10. The trackpad works fine when I am using the Windows OS, but it glitches out on the Ubuntu 24.04. The trackpad keeps rapidly clicking, when it is interacted with, almost as if it is cycling through both the left and right buttons when the cursor is in motion, a regular USB mouse works fine. I currently turn off the trackpad using sudo rmmod psmouse. I have tried some of the fixes I have seen, but most of them are for older versions of the Ubuntu, they do not work. Anyone has any idea what to do about this.

What are the exact fixes you have tried so no one gives you the same suggestions again? Please answer with an edit to the question and not as a comment.
